# What are examples of appropriate/smart strategies for professors to approach/deal with unmotivated students in class?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, teaching

When I teach lower level undergraduate math classes (mandatory for general science/eigineering majors), there are always students wearing a dull expression and staying silent all the time. I can feel they probably didn't understand what I taught but when I asked "is this part clear?" or "does this make sense?" they also didn't make any responses. This can be very frustrating sometimes.

I wonder what are examples of appropriate/smart ways for professors to approach/deal with unmotivated students in class? I understand it is common for professors to just leave the unmotivated students alone since they were not voluntarily taking this class from the beginning. But this kind of attitute looks very irresponsible to me as a teacher. Can anyone share some helpful strategies?